# How to solve leader's problem in stackelberg game when follower's optimal decision is implicit function of model parameters?

Tags: game-theory

Suppose there is a leader with net profit function $EC(P_{1},Y,X)$ where $P_{1},Y$ are decision variables of leader. The follower's problem is given as follows:
$$\max_{X}ENP(P_{1},Y,X)=\max_{X}P_{1}X-c_{1}(X^2+\sigma^2)-p_{1}\int_{LB}^{Y-X}(Y-X-\epsilon)f(\epsilon)d\epsilon$$ where $c_{1},p_{1}$ are parameters of the model and $X$ is follower's decision variable. Here $\epsilon$ is random variable with support in $[LB,UB]$ ,probability density function $f(.)$ and cumulative distribution function $F(.)$. The follower's problem is solved. $ENP$ is concave function of follower's decision variable $X$ with optimal $X$ coming from first order condition given by:$P_{1}-2c_{1}X^{*}+p_{1}F(Y-X^{*})=0$. From this expression it can be seen that $X^{*}$ is an implicit function of model parameters and customer's decision variables. Then how do we substitute $X^{*}$ in leader's problem and solve the leader's problem.

Comment: What have you tried? People don't like to answer homework questions, unless there has been show some effort. Your question is not also very clear.

Comment: my idea is to optimize the leader's problem with the first order condition expression as equality constraint.

Comment: @Pradipta Why don't you try your idea and post it here as an answer (you can answer your own question) ? It sounds promising.